# Regular expression - range of the match

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
re.findall(r'(\b[A-Za-z][a-z]{3,10}\b)', string_var)
```

I expected that this regular expression will return matches with the length ranging from `3` to `10`. It however returns matches for words ranging in length from `4` to `11`.

Do we thus read the above regular expression as matching those words which start with an upper case or lower case letter, followed by letters ranging in length from `3` to `10`? In other words, having the first letter as the extra letter which extended the range?

Thanks.

Comment: Your matches will range from 4 to 11 letters long. The `{3, 10}` quantifier (i.e. at least three and no more than ten) only applies to the second character set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry I entered 8 instead of 11, and 7 instead of 10. I have fixed that in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Your regex is

```
(\b[A-Za-z][a-z]{3,10}\b)
```

Now, the grouping parens don't affect the match, so we can ignore them. And the `\b` is a "zero-width" matching operator - it matches a transition from one character class to another - so it doesn't actually correspond to any characters. We can ignore them. That leaves this:

```
[A-Za-z][a-z]{3,10}
```

This is two character classes, with a repetition specifier suffix on the second:

1. [A-Za-z] - matches one character, upper or lower case Latin alphabetic.
2. [a-z]{3,10} - matches at least 3, at most 10 characters, lowercase a-z

So in total, you are matching 1 + [3,10] character. Your minimal match will be 4 characters, and your maximal match will be 11.